self supervised model converging to a constant
I was trying to train a Barlow twins model for image classification. Nonetheless, I encountered a problem after finishing my model training. It seems that the model has become a constant always returning the number 2046 with a slightly variable decimal part no matter how different the two giving images are.
The model tries to minimize the cross correlation matrix to the identity matrix.
is there a way to overcome this problem.
def off_diagonal(x):
    # return a flattened view of the off-diagonal elements of a square matrix

class BarlowTwins(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, lambd ,batch_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.lambd = lambd
        self.backbone = torchvision.models.resnet34(zero_init_residual=True, weights='DEFAULT')
        self.backbone.fc = nn.Identity()
        self.sizes = [512,2048,2048,2048]


        # projector
        _sizes = [512,4096,4096,4096]

        layers = []
        for i in range(len(self.sizes) - 2):
            layers.append(nn.Linear(self.sizes[i], self.sizes[i + 1], bias=False))
            layers.append(nn.BatchNorm1d(self.sizes[i + 1]))
            layers.append(nn.ReLU(inplace=True))
        layers.append(nn.Linear(self.sizes[-2], self.sizes[-1], bias=False))
        self.projector = nn.Sequential(*layers)

        # normalization layer for the representations z1 and z2
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm1d(self.sizes[-1], affine=False)

    def forward(self, y1, y2):
        z1 = self.projector(self.backbone(y1))
        z2 = self.projector(self.backbone(y2))

        # empirical cross-correlation matrix
        c = self.bn(z1).T @ self.bn(z2)

        # sum the cross-correlation matrix between all gpus
        c.div_(self.batch_size)

        on_diag = torch.diagonal(c).add_(-1).pow_(2).sum()
        # print('c', c)
        val = torch.diagonal(c).sum()

        off_diag = off_diagonal(c).pow_(2).sum()
        # print('off_diag', off_diag)
        
        loss = on_diag + self.lambd * off_diag 
        return loss, val

from tqdm import tqdm



def intiate_p(model, epoch_n, loader, print_freq, lr, momentum, weight_decay):
    epoch_tqdm = tqdm(range(epoch_n))
    param_weights = []
    param_biases = []
    r = print_freq
    func = model


    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=lr, momentum=momentum, weight_decay=weight_decay)
  

    scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.PolynomialLR(optimizer, total_iters=40, power=2.0)


    losses = []

    # target = torch.tensor(2048, dtype=torch.float32)
    start_time = time.time()
    stats_file = open('stats.txt', 'a', buffering=1)

    
    for epoch in epoch_tqdm:
        
        for step, ((y1, y2), _) in enumerate(loader, start=epoch * len(loader)):

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss = func.forward(y1, y2)[0]
            losses.append(loss)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            scheduler.step()
            epoch_tqdm.set_description(f"the Loss is: {abs(loss -2048)}  " )

  
    return losses

The problem here is that I am not sure whether my approach for the evaluation of the model was correct. because I randomly fed two images as y1 and y2 to my model for one 100 iterations but the results remain constant.
Side notes: I have tried many different values for training variables and the best loss I could get was 100.
md = BarlowTwins(batch_size=64, lambd=0.005)
t = intiate_p(model=md, epoch_n=20, loader=loader,lr=0.4,momentum=0.3 ,print_freq=10, weight_decay=0.0001)
# the loss converges to about a 100 while it started from around 2000

This an example of the histogram of the different acquired values:

